# How to select XML element based on tag name using Jquery selectors?

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

If I have an XML document and I am parsing it using Jquery selectors (using the [CheerioJS](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) module), how can I grab the value of the value, task, and data tag of the first item without basing it on child position, ie basing it on the actual name of the tag instead?

```
<head>
  <item>
    <value>input</value> //how do I grab this value using Jquery selectors?
    <task>input</task>
    <data>input</data>
  </item>
  <item>
    <value>input</value>
    <task>input</task>
    <data>input</data>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the content of the *first* value tag, use this:

```
$("value").first().text();
```

If you want to iterate through *all* value tags, use this:

```
$("value").each(function(){
    $(this).text(); 
});
```

If you want the values of all children of the first item tag, use this:

```
$("item").first().children().each(function(){
    $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer which is definitely correct in this situation, but ultimately my sample code was an oversimplification and to use your solution in my project unfortunately won't work. I need to able to grab the values of the tags within the first item based on it being the first item. Based on your sample code I think something like $("item").first(). ___ <-- and then the code to be able to grab the values of the tags based on their tag name in the underlined section. If you know the answer for that it'd be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I added a solution for what I think you want. If it's still not it, please provide a better example with the expected output.

Comment: Okay, awesome, thank you that's exactly what I was looking for. The other thing I needed was the tagname of each, which I've selected using $(this).get(0).tagName which seems to be working correctly, is that what you would recommend for the job? Thanks again!